# slds-icon-utility-xxx class not work after Summer 20 Release

Tags: visualforce, slds, summer20

I face an issue after Summer 20 release. Currently looks like slds-icon-utility-xxx class not work in both Lightning Experience and Classic Mode.

My Code:

```
    <apex:page >
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en">
        <apex:slds />
        <span class="slds-icon_container">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon">
                <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#opened_folder')}"></use>
            </svg>
             <span class="slds-assistive-text">Account Icon</span>
        </span>
        
        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-announcement">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon">
                <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#opened_folder')}"></use>
            </svg>
             <span class="slds-assistive-text">Account Icon</span>
        </span>
        
        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon">
                <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#opened_folder')}"></use>
            </svg>
             <span class="slds-assistive-text">Account Icon</span>
        </span>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Phenomenon

[image: Classic Mode]

[image: Lightning Experience]

You can see only icon add slds-icon-standard-xxx class show. May I ask you idea about this issue and please correct me if I code wrong.

Notes:
This code works fine before Summer 20 release.

Best wishes,
Lee

Comment: It is present in SLDS for Summer20, you can see here(for the opened folder icon, you can inspect the same icon, you'll see same SVG path).  - https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/#utility

Also, if you want to show icons, I'd suggest trying lightning:icon tag.

Comment: Hi Ysr Shk, 

Sorry for repeat late. I can't lightning:icon for this case, I check the link you give to me, no help.

Comment: @GhostLee Check my response here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/315580/aura-components-utility-icons-not-showing-after-summer-20-update/315609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue documented [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001SqocQAC).

The issue has been identified as a Chrome issue than the salesforce issue. The timing of the chrome issue and Salesforce release is a coincidence. You can follow the bug here

Hopefully, this will be resolved with the next Chrome update.

**UPDATE**

- This has been fixed now by chrome!

Comment: Hi Mohith:

I check the document you share to me. I test previous Chrome and beta version Chrome. You're right this is a Chrome issue. Thank you for your remind.

Best wishes,
Lee