# Aura components: Utility icons not showing after Summer 20 update

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, icon

With recent release our team has started facing this intermittent issue of utility icons not showing in buttons and button icons.

**Button icon code:**

```
<lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:save"  alternativeText="Save" onclick="{!c.handleSave}" 
                                disabled="{!v.disableSave}"/>
```

**Button code:**

```
<lightning:button label="Mass Update" onclick="{!c.showMassUpdate}" title="Mass Update"
                    iconName="utility:record_update" iconPosition="left" variant="Neutral"
                    disabled="{!v.disableMassUpdate}" />
```

Any leads on how we can resolve this issue?

Comment: works fine for me

Comment: Do you see any error in the console or network tab? Can you check with different browsers or increasing the API version of the component and let us know the results.

Comment: Duplicate of - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313802/slds-icon-utility-xxx-class-not-work-after-summer-20-release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been identified as a Chrome issue than the salesforce issue. The timing of the chrome issue and Salesforce release is a coincidence. You can follow the bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1107442)

Hopefully, this will be resolved with the next chrome update.

You can follow the known issue [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001SqocQAC)

**UPDATE**

This has been fixed now by chrome!

Comment: Thanks Mohith for the quick response! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

There have been issues with utility icons reported in the past and Salesforce identified them as bugs. I recommend raising a support case to confirm the behavior

[utility:pin and utility:pinned icons mentioned in the LightningDesignSystem are not rendered in the Lightning components](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCF0QAM)

[Work Utility icons on community pages disappear from the page when the chat button is clicked](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000KTnWQAW)

Notice that both the utility icons specified in the question are working consistently in the [lightning playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/499fb515a9ecee5f7392f01a2f257f33641c836d/edit)